# How to backup a running SQL Server CE database with full data?

Tags: backup, sql-server-compact

I need to move my running windows-based app (built in C#) to another machine, but I also need to transfer the whole data, how can I take a backup from the `.sdf` file and use it with the new installed app?

I tried to take a copy of the `.sdf` file, but I couldn't find it !

Any help ? ...

Comment: Find the file - copy it - done!

Comment: How can you not find the .sdf file? That is like writing to `/dev/null`.

Comment: I tried to search any *.sdf in the whole machine but i couldn't find it !!

Comment: @Alzayed: It will tell you in the connection string.

Comment: in connection string it is only : Data Source=|DataDirectory|<database_filename.sdf>

Comment: How to find the database path: See my blog post here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/02/sql-server-compact-code-snippet-of-week_19.html

Comment: *Data Source=|DataDirectory|<database_filename.sdf>* --> so go to your web application, find the `App_Data` directory --> that's where the `.sdf` file will be